# how to exclude java sources from a third party jar?

Tags: java, maven-2

I have one jar dependency in my java project that contains sources as well and when I run mvn compile, these java sources appear as class files in my compiled maven output :(...
How can I exclude these files.. (I only want my own compiled files in the compiled output)

I tried something like:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <configuration>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>**/bv/**/*.java</exclude>
   </excludes>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Played with it but they keep appearing in my maven compiled output :( ..

Any idea's ?

Comment: What do you mean by your "maven compiled output"?  Do you just mean that the 3rd-party lib containing source-code is in your WAR file?

Comment: What do you mean by "that contains sources as well"?  Do you mean that the JAR contains source code AND compiled code?

Comment: Check out - http://old.nabble.com/Maven-compile-puts-javax.servlet.&2A-in-target-classes-td27135933.html - describes this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that this is a normal behavior of [`javac`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) that searches the whole classpath for source files to compile unless the `-sourcepath` option is given (and this would be the solution here).

Unfortunately, there is a Jira issue about `-sourcepath` not being passed to `javac` by the Maven Compiler Plugin (see [MCOMPILER-98](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-98)) but there is a workaround. So, could you please try this:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <compilerArguments>
      <sourcepath>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourcepath>
    </compilerArguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Exactly, I also noticed the issue when trying to solve it...
Did notice the workaround however.
Thanks, I seems to work.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Would the provided scope work?

From: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html:

> This is much like compile, but
>   indicates you expect the JDK or a
>   container to provide the dependency at
>   runtime.

Comment: No, because it's has to be packed finally in a war file, so I can't see how this work... Now I have the third party source classes packaged in my own jar as class files and the third party jar with his classes and source... :(... Doesn't sound very healty...

Comment: Let me see if I've got this right: Your jar has dependencies on a 3rd party jar, which also needs to be compiled. The 3rd party jar and your jar will then be included in the war...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `-implicit:none` parameter to the compiler

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <compilerArgument>-implicit:none</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```